# backup of ubuntu

Tags: backup

I have Ubuntu installed on a single 1TB drive. What I want to do is a full backup of the system. I know I can use tar/gzip or rsync for most of the data, but I'm not sure what exactly do I need to do to be able to restore fully functional (bootable) system.
Here is how my drive looks like:

```
Device   Start        End    Sectors  Size Type 
/dev/nvme1n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System 
/dev/nvme1n1p2 1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux filesystem
```

would it be enough to make a clone of the `/dev/nvme1n1p1` like dd `if=/dev/nvme1n1p1 of=/backup/boot.img bs=4m` and then simply do the rsync for the other directories (something like `rsync -Lrau --ignore-errors --delete --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/cdrom/*,/lost+found} / /backup/system`). Then after the system is broken (or after replacing the ssd drive for example) I just clone the `nvme1n1p1` back via `dd` and copy the data. Would that make the system bootable and functional?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you actually want a "bootable clone" instead of a "full backup". Try searching using that term.

Comment: While it can be done, you would still need to install the bootloader after restoring the tar/rsync backup for the system to be bootable. Just restoring EFI partition is not enough. Here is a short tutorial how to reinstall GRUB on your system: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/grub-rescue#ftoc-heading-7 Also `/etc/fstab` may need fixing if partition UUIDs change. It is better to `dd` your `/dev/nvme1n1p2` to some backup image file as well (probably on some external drive) instead of using tar/rsync.

Answer (score 3):

I do a weekly Deja-Dup backup of my home directory and once a month, and before any upgrades, I do a bare-metal backup using Clonezilla. I have been doing this since Ubuntu 10.04 and my Clonezilla backups have always restored a working system if ever anything goes wrong. You can get Clonezilla [here](https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php), it is open source GPL software.

Install Clonezilla onto a bootable USB stick and have a USB harddisk ready to use as a repository for the backup.

Comment: Do you clone just the system partition (`/`) or the whole disk? What about the EFI System Partition (ESP)? Please clarify in the answer.

Comment: @user68186 I clone the whole disc including the EFI partition. That is what "Bare-metal backup" means. I have even replaced the laptop harddisc and restored the previous system onto it without issue.